# PHP: parse text from Database line by line

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing a `text` datatype in a database that contains newlines (cr + lf). It is accessed by, for example, `$row['mytext']`. How can I read `$row['mytext']` line by line to do some parsing prior to outputting to html? I know how to do this with a file but have never done it with `text` from a database.

Comment: Show us what you have so far for code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have `$row['mytext']` it is just a string so you can just explode on new lines and then iterate through the array.

Example:

```
$string = 'line 1
line2';
foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to hear about that "rabbit" hole you fell into earlier Chris. I knew [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33071558/) was going nowhere. Maybe this will make up for it. You have a LOT more patience than I do ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, I had a feeling I was walking into that on the first comment but figured it couldn't go as far as it did.

Comment: You're welcome Chris. Plus the fact that `db.php` was a Pandora's box and the rest of *whatever's in their db*, wow. I swear to you, I'll bet you would be a great "cactus grower" ;-) *Cheers man*.

Comment: Oh btw, that question, was a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069170/login-system-not-functioning - Had I checked first, I would have closed it from the get-go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- hah, I'll have to look into this cactus growing. Looks like a similar outcome on that question as well. OP needs to learn to debug; never going to be able to resolve their issues.

Comment: With the patience you have, it'll be a breeze! I grow them myself. I used to have about 1500 at one point. I'm down to about a few hundred now (long story). Yeah, too bad for all that have been dragged into those questions. I usually put the brakes on after 10-15 mins., and that one made my *"Spidey sense"* tingle ;-)